# cudaTextureObject_t texFetch1D doesn't compile

Tags: c++, cuda, textures

this code doesn't compile in cuda toolkit 7.5 on a gtx 980 with compute capability set to 5.2 in visual studio 2013.

```
__global__ void a_kernel(cudaTextureObject_t texObj)
{
    int thread_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int something = tex1Dfetch(texObj, thread_id);
}
```

here is the error.

```
error : more than one instance of overloaded function "tex1Dfetch" matches the argument list:
```

this code also doesn't compile.

```
__global__ void another_kernel(cudaTextureObject_t texObj)
{
    int thread_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    float something = tex1Dfetch<float>(texObj, thread_id);
}
```

here is that error.

```
error : type name is not allowed
```

following this example and the comments, all of the above should work:
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/

please let me know if you need additional info, I couldn't think what else to provide.

Comment: You need to show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code that reproduces your error. Just like you link, with the code on how you lanch the kernel and how you create the Tex obj.

Answer (score 2):

Your first kernel doesn't compile because of a missing template type argument. This will compile:

```
__global__ void a_kernel(cudaTextureObject_t texObj)
{
    int thread_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int something = tex1Dfetch<int>(texObj, thread_id);
}
```

Your second kernel is correct, and it *does* compile for me using VS2012 with the CUDA 7.0 toolkit for every compute capability I tried (sm_30 through sm_52).

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the cuda toolkit and now the second piece of code (another_kernel) compiles. The first piece of code was incorrect in the first place as per the first answer. W.r.t. reinstalling the cuda toolkit, it was that I must have previously clobbered something in the sdk, I believe it was texture_indirect_functions.h.